# Vim Error for Git Commit Message

Tags: save

When using vim as my default editor, I (occasionally) accidentally pull up search (e.g. via `/wq` instead of `:wq`). Once I do, I escape out of search, and then exit correctly via `:wq`. However, when that happens, I see the following error message:

```
 hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... error: There was a problem with the editor 'vi'.
 Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

I'm trying to understand why vi is not exiting correctly, or how I can fix it to exit correctly even after a failed search.

I am using macOS High Sierra.

```
 VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Nov 29 2017 18:37:46)
 Included patches: 1-503, 505-680, 682-1283
```

Steps to reproduce:

```
 > git commit
 vim> i
 vim> My Commit Message
 vim> <Esc>
 vim> /wq
 vim> <Esc>
 vim> :wq
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You shouldn't need the second ESC there. You say "I escape out of search" in the question text too - what state do you find Vi in after the `/wq`, what happens if you press `:wq` without the second ESC?

Comment: Good point, though the error still persists without the extra escape.

Comment: You may want to change the config to `vi` instead of vim

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is possible that you have `EDITOR` left unset or to its default value of `vi`. Try making `vim` your editor. Although both `vi` and `vim` are the same executable in mac, I guess, vim behaves in a minimalist way when invoked as vi than vim.

`git config --global core.editor /usr/bin/vim`

Comment: Great-- you're right that I did not have a default editor set. When I set the editor to `usr/bin/vim` it works as expected, and if I change it back to `/usr/bin/vi` it fails like above. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Wow, never thought that invoking _Vim_ as `vi` would cause this kind of problems. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience using the graphical `gvim`, I have to set `git config --global core.editor "gvim -f"` to make sure it properly waits for the editor to close. The `-f` option is also available for `vi` and `vim`. Try this if git is having trouble waiting for the editor to close.